# Spring not find controller when run application

Tags: spring-mvc

I've read so many topics that had same issue with my case from here but found nothing to solve my problem. This is my servlet configuration using namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="fi.vietjob" />


    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views 
        directory -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "welcome" view -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />

    <!-- location of static content (images, js and css files) -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:lang" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="vn" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!--config for upload image -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver" />
</beans>
```

Here is my stackstrace when restarting server

```
 Jan 11, 2017 9:34:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:   Sep 24 2014 09:01:51
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:  8.0.14.0
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:        Mac OS X
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:     10.10.5
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:   x86_64
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:    1.8.0_11-b12
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/dinhthinh/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:17 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:vietduuni' did not find a matching property.
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8001"]
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:18 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:18 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1064 ms
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:18 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'vietjob'
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8001"]
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 11, 2017 9:34:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7262 ms
```

web.xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

 <listener>
    <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
<!-- Servlet config begin -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>vietjob</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>vietjob</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<!-- end-->

   <filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
  </filter-mapping> 


   <!-- Begin load Spring Filter Chain config from servlet vietjob -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/vietjob-security.xml
        </param-value>
   </context-param>

    <!-- end load -->
    <!-- Begin Spring security config-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When i run my application, nothing errors found but in stacktrace it not showing text row that inform controllers were loaded. So when i hit the link, i got 404 error. Anyone can help me?!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't shared how you started your application.

For any spring web application you have to provide the configuration for DispatcherServlet in your application.

**Method 1**
You could put below mapping in your web.xml file

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myWebApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myWebApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

**Method 2**
You could register a bean implementing interface WebApplicationInitializer and could register DispatcherServlet programmatically

Now bean configuration file name should be {servlet-name}-servlet.xml

So for above servlet, bean configuration file name should be myWebApp-servlet.xml

Or if you want to customize the name of your bean configuration file, then you can mention it inside the web.xml as below

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myWebApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myWebApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing log4j12 dependency in pom.xml file resolved my problem.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```